# How to provide permission access to directories and files in windows-phone-8

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my windows-phone-8 application I'm trying to delete the files from the directory **c:\Data\SharedData\OEM\Public**

I can able to copy the files from that directory location but I cannot able to do move or  delete operations. Getting **UnauthorizedAccessException(access path is denied)** exception.

We also tried creating one more folder inside the above mentioned location but even in that folder we couldn't do delete or move operations.

Changing folder permission will resolve this issue? If so please share the information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone applications can only access files in their own sandboxed area of "isolated storage". It is not possible to access, change or modify files or folders outside this area.

There is no way to share files via the file system.

If you can let us know what you are trying to ultimately achieve then we may be able to suggest an alternative.